# Comparing proxy metrics to human evaluations

Tags: ranking, reliability, calibration

I have two proxy metrics, and I'd like to see which of them correlates more strongly with human ratings. I have ~30 questions, and for each question 3 humans independently give a score on a 1-10 scale. The questions vary in how subjective the scores are, perhaps significantly (in other words, some questions should have a fairly obvious "10" score, while other questions leave a lot of room for reasonable disagreement). The actual scores themselves don't matter too much, the rank order across the 30 questions is really more important (the highest scoring questions should also be the highest scoring according to the proxy metric).

I'd like to answer (a) which proxy metric correlates more strongly with the human evaluations and (b) how statistically significant is this improvement in correlation (c) are the proxy metrics "at least as good as a human?" In other words, if the correlation turns out to be weak, that's fine with me IF the correlations between the scores of the humans just as weak.

I'm not primarily a stats person, though I did take a course in college many years ago and am willing and capable to do some reading if required. I'm quite comfortable with python, and can use scipy, etc.. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: When you say "correlates with human rating", you seem to imply that you want to compare to a mean of a sample of humans taking into account the variability of human responses. So if are ok with ignoring correlations between responses to different questions, you could just take the distance of each proxy response to the mean human response, divided by the standard deviation of the human responses for that question. This would give you a per-question distance of proxy from a typical human. The 30 or so (one per-question) distances can then be averaged.

Comment: I suppose my questions could then be answered as (a) whichever proxy metric has the lowest variance after subtracting the human mean and dividing by human stddev is better (b) if the proxies are "human like" then after the suggested transform the proxy scores should be standard normal; use this as the hypothesis for a significance test (c) if the metrics are as good as a human, the stddev after the transform should be <=1. Correct?

Comment: (a) Almost correct, I'd use sum of squared errors (which is variance + bias^2) rather than just variance, in order to make sure bias is not ignored. (b) "human like", in my mind, can only be tested if the correlations between responses are accounted for, which is not possible given your human sample size, but there might be other valid interpretation of that phrase. (c) The general direction sounds correct, but I'm not sure right now what the exact interpretation of a particular stddev such as 1 would be (might be better to think in terms of p-value)